# TypeScript infer the callback return type in type constructor

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

I want to write a type constructor for a function which receives a type `S` and a function from `S` to another type then applies that function on the `S` and returns the result:

```
// This works but it's tied to the implementation
function dig<S, R>(s: S, fn: (s: S) => R): R {
  return fn(s);
}

// This works as separate type constructor but I have to specify `R`
type Dig<S, R> = (s: S, fn: (s: S) => R) => R;

// Generic type 'Dig' requires 2 type argument(s).
const d: Dig<string> = (s, fn) => fn(s);
```

So how can I write a `Dig<S>` type constructor which infers the return type of the passed `fn` argument without me specifying the `R`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of TS3.4 there is no support for [partial type argument inference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242), so you can't easily have the compiler let you specify `S` but infer `R`.  But from your example, it doesn't look like you want to *infer* `R` as some concrete type, but allow it to remain generic so that the return type of `fn` can be whatever it wants to be when you *call* `d()`.

So it looks like you really want this type:

```
type Dig<S> = <R>(s: S, fn: (s: S) => R) => R;
```

This is sort of a "doubly generic" type, in the sense that once you specify `S` you've still got a generic function dependent on `R`.  This should work for the example you gave:

```
const d: Dig<string> = (s, fn) => fn(s);

const num = d("hey", (x) => x.length); // num is inferred as number
const bool = d("you", (x) => x.indexOf("z") >= 0); // bool inferred as boolean
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Fantastic. I knew about the `doubly generic` type from flow but had no idea TS supports it.

Comment: Is there any official doc for `doubly generic`?

Comment: I'm just using the term "doubly generic" for lack of something better.. can't find a doc at the moment

Comment: A good discussion of the types of generics in TypeScript is here in an issue called [Generic values](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574).  The `Dig` definition I gave is a combination of a generic *type* (type polymorphism) with a generic *function* (value polymorphism).

Comment: Very nice. Thanks.

Comment: @jcalz hi what if it i wanted to make the callback function optional? and if leaving it optional would return a number by default. i tried making it optional but typescript is complaining that "'R' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'number | R'." that make sense but I couldn't find any solution or any workaround for this.