# Why can't Typescript infer the type of a nested generic function?

Tags: typescript

Typescript types the `state` argument to the `applyReducer` call below as `unknown`. It works if I explicitly specify the type with `applyReducer<State>`, but why is this necessary? It seems pretty clear the type should be `State`.

(Typescript v4.1.2)

**reducerFlow.ts:**

```js
type UnaryReducer<S> = (state: S) => S

export const applyReducer = <S>(reducer: UnaryReducer<S>) =>
  (state: S) => reducer(state)
```

**foo.ts**

```js
interface State { a: number, b: number }
const initialState: State = { a: 0, b: 0 }

// Why is the type of state unknown?
// Typescript can't infer that it is State?
const foo = applyReducer(
    state => ({ ...state, b: state.b + 1 })
)(initialState)
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/PTAECcFMBMFcGNLgGIBsD2B3AdAFwM4CwAUCbgJ4AOkoAqgHYCG45ASjAkgDwDKAfKAC8oABT5cjXJABcoHgEohAniRKQAHpXThcoeOnrjQjSpVRsOicENC8+IqHCuyGzC0+79FgviVCjxSRk5bwFHTnAxCSl5VVJiEFAAM3R0PCJ4gEt6KXAkxkQ5aJoAb2NZelgAWwAjJAAaUBqK6rrrAF8SfUNdbMzcTMZUHmLZEaCbMsZZAAZG5tAZ0E74xIB1AAtyUEz8UFwNmgpqUHQk0ECpUFh6AGt6LHoAfhJEgBUqSHx4cEzKXXgjHoAHJevQkkh9htJDtentxlIXsRukYUugbCYzO4IiI-BdikpRGVsCTLpB5rIydgaqAANSgACMy1ixHkIj6AyGCMg8iAA)

Comment: It's clear *to you*, but all TypeScript knows is it takes something and returns something that has a `b` prop! The use of `initialState` is *after* the call to `applyReducer` completes, the type won't be inferred from that.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57076303/infer-types-from-reducer-function

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
Here is my answer:

Example:

```js
type UnaryReducer = <S>(state: S) => S

interface ApplyReducer {
  <T extends UnaryReducer>(reducer: T): <S,>(state: ReturnType<T> & S) => ReturnType<T> & S;
}

export const applyReducer: ApplyReducer = (reducer) =>
  (state) => reducer(state)


interface State { a: number, b: number }
const initialState: State = { a: 0, b: 0 }


const bar = applyReducer(
  state => ({ ...state, b: 2, })
)(initialState)
bar // {b: number; } & State

const bar2 = applyReducer(
  state => ({ ...state, b: '2', }) 
)(initialState) // Error: b is not a string

const bar3 = applyReducer(
  state => ({ ...state, b: 2, c:'2' }) 
)(initialState) // Error: Property 'c' is missing in type 'State'
 
const bar4 = applyReducer(
  state => ({ ...state }) 
)(initialState) // Ok

const bar5 = applyReducer(
  state => ({ a: 0, b: 0 }) // Error: you should always return object wich is extended by State
)(initialState)

const bar6 = applyReducer(
  state => ({...state, a: 0, b: 0 }) // Ok
)(initialState)
```

We should define generic parameter directly for arrow function

```js
type UnaryReducer = <S>(state: S) => S
```

We should somehow bind `initialState` argument and ReturnType of reducer

```js
interface ApplyReducer {
  <T extends UnaryReducer>(reducer: T): <S,>(state: ReturnType<T> & S) => ReturnType<T> & S;
}
```

It is mean that `state` argument of reducer (callback) should be always a part of return type.

That's mean, that if you will try to:

```js
state => ({ a:0, b: 2, })
```

it is not gonna work, but I think there is not sence to do it

**UPDATE**
I think it is impossible to do. Consider this example:

```js
const foo = applyReducer(
  state => ({ ...state, b: state.b + 1 })
)

const result = foo((initialState))
```

You are able to infer `initialState` only during `foo` call. NO way TS will know upfront the argument  type during `foo` declaration.

TS infers arguments from left to right.

Comment: You lose the type safety this way. For example, try to return `({ ...state, b: '' })`. That should give an error but doesn't.

Comment: @JeffreyWesterkamp you are right. I will try to fix it

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That is an improvement in some ways, but unfortunately not in the way that is important to me: being able to infer that `state` is of type `State` within the reducer definition. I need to be able to use `state` within the function, e.g. `state => { ...state, b: state.b + 1 }`. I have updated the OP.

Comment: @RaineRevere please take a look on this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31146 and this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55655707/typescript-infer-the-callback-return-type-in-type-constructor
Maybe smbd else will be able to answer it

Comment: @captain-yossarian Thanks for the references! I'll keep an eye on them.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

> It works if I explicitly specify the type with applyReducer, but why is this necessary?

The problem is with the fact that this is a curried function, i.e. `(x) => (y) => z`. Because the type parameter `S` is on the first function it will 'instantiate' (get a concrete type) as soon as you call that function. You can see that in action by looking at the type of `fn` below:

```
const fn = applyReducer((state) => ({ ...state, b: 2 }))
//                                    ^^^^^^^^ error (because you can't spread 'unknown')
//
// const fn: (state: unknown) => unknown
```

Because in the argument `(state) => ({ ...state, b: 2 })` there is no information available about what `S` should become, typescript defaults to [`unknown`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type). So `S` is unknown now, and regardless of what you call `fn` with afterwards, it will stay unknown.

One way to fix this is to - as you mentioned - explicitly provide the type argument:

```
const fna = applyReducer<State>((state) => ({ ...state, b: 2 }))
```

And another way is to give typescript some information from where it can infer the type for `S`, for example a type constraint on the `state` parameter:

```
const fnb = applyReducer((state: State) => ({ ...state, b: 2 }))
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This seems like a bug in Typescript. `fn` indeed does not have enough type information to infer the type of `state`, but `fn(...)(initialState)` has the type of `initialState` at compile-time. Similarly, `<T>(x: T) => x` cannot infer the type of `x` on its own, but can in `(<T>(x: T) => x)(10)`, i.e. `x` *can* be inferred from the argument provider later in the call expression. It fails to do the same thing for curried functions.