# Infer function generic type U from return value of passed function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, inferred-type

A function with a generic type may infer the generic types from the arguments in most cases. However, if an argument is a function where the generic type is both part of the arguments and the return value, the generic type is sometimes not inferred.

Dumbed down example with a class for storing items, and where some attributes of items are auto-generated (e.g. a database where IDs are auto-generated):

```
/**
 * Stores items of type T
 */
class Store<T> {

  /**
   * Return a function that creates items from supplied partial items merged with
   * attributes U auto-generated by a generator function
   */
  itemCreator<U>(
    generate: (item: Omit<T, keyof U>) => U
  ): (item: Omit<T, keyof U>) => Omit<T, keyof U> & U {
    return item => ({...item, ...generate(item)});
  }
}

type Person = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  age?: number;
};
```

So, if you create a `Store<Person>` and supply a generator to auto-generate `id`, the returned creator function would only require `name` and `email`.

However, in some cases, `U` is not inferred:

Works:

```
const create = new Store<Person>()
  .itemCreator(() => ({id: 'ID', extra: 42}));
// U is {id: string, extra: number}, `create` only needs to provide `name` and `email` :)
const person = create({name: 'John', email: 'john.doe@foo.com'}); // creates person with extra
```

Does not work:

```
const create = new Store<Person>()
  .itemCreator(item => ({id: 'ID', extra: 42}));
// U is now unknown, meaning the `create` function must provide complete `Person` objects :(
const person = create({name: 'John', email: 'john.doe@foo.com'}); // does not compile
```

Works with explicit `<U>`:

```
const create = new Store<Person>()
  .itemCreator<{id: string, extra: number}>((item) => ({id: 'ID', extra: 42}));
const person = create({name: 'John', email: 'john.doe@foo.com'}); // creates person with extra
```

Now, the reason for passing the partial item to the generator is that some auto-generated attributes might be dependent on other attributes (such as an `id` being generated as a hash of an `email` attribute):

```
const creator = new Store<Person>()
  .itemCreator(item => ({id: hash(item.email)}))
```

So, my question is why inferring `U` fails if the argument to the `generate` function is provided? Does TypeScript simply use the first found instance of `U` or what is the reason? The `generate` function returns `U`, so if it sees `{id: string}` being returned, one could argue that the fact that `U` is also present in the `Omit` type of the *argument* to `generate` should be irrelevant?

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: I think, here might be the same problem as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64975281/why-cant-typescript-infer-the-type-of-a-nested-generic-function/64976295#64976295

Comment: This is really interesting!  I'm not sure how to solve it -- it's a tough one.  It would be a lot easier if the callback took the whole `Person` object  but we want the args and the return type to depend on each other.  I think what's happening is that the args gets evaluated first but we want the return type to be evaluated first, and I don't know how we can change that behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@JHH, @Linda Paiste what do you think about next solution ?:

```js
class Store<T> {

    itemCreator<U>(
        generate: <P = Omit<T, keyof U>>(item: P) => U
    ): (item: Omit<T, keyof U>) => Omit<T, keyof U> & U {
        return item => ({ ...item, ...generate(item) });
    }
}

type Person = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    email: string;
    age?: number;
};


const create = new Store<Person>()
    .itemCreator(item => {
        const x = item // Omit<Person, "id" | "extra">
        return ({ id: 'ID', extra: 42 })
    });
const person = create({ name: 'John', email: 'john.doe@foo.com' });
```

It is looks like it is hard for TS to infer `item` argument, so I defined extra generic with default value.

[Here](https://catchts.com/callbacks), in my blog, you can find more interesting callback typings

[Here](https://twitter.com/captainyosarian/status/1373613358348447746) you can find explanation of this behaviour by Titian Cernicova Dragomir

> If there is a parameter, the checker needs to decide U before checking the body, since there is no source for inference it goes with unknown. It then checks the body, but does not go back to try again with `U = ret type` it just checks the return compa. with U = unknown

Comment: Nice work!  Definitely looks like it's inferring properly.  I'm always telling people to use fewer generics so it's ironic that adding an extra generic was the solution here :)

Comment: Thanks! Also, I dont understand why it did not work and why my solution works :D

Comment: I don't understand it fully either, but if I had to guess: `P` having a default value which depends on `U` forces `U` to be evaluated first?  Which is what we want.

Comment: That's awesome - but very weird! When I tried your solution, at first I added `generate: <P extends Omit<T, keyof U> = Omit<T, keyof U>>(item: P) => U`, and that did NOT work, but an unbound `P` with a default value works. So it doesn't seem as easy as what @LindaPaiste suggested - that having P depend on U forces it to be evaluated first. I was considering posting an issue on TypeScript to get Ryan's opinion. Thanks for already reaching out to him on Twitter! :)

Comment: Yes, I agree, this is weird, but I think that we just don't understand how TS compiler works. Most of the time I'm going intuitively :) with TypeScript

Comment: @captain-yossarian I ran into a problem today which may be related and/or have the same root cause, if you're interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66777727/avoid-inferring-as-least-common-denominator-of-array-elements