# Avoid inferring as least common denominator of array elements

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

If a function has a generic parameter `<T>` and takes an array of items related to `T`, it seems `T` is always inferred as the intersection of all elements, even if `T` could also be inferred from the return type of the function.
Example:

```
type Item = {foo: string, bar: number};

// A List<Item> may contain items containing partial Items such as {foo: 'FOO'}, {bar: 42}
interface List<T> {
  items: Array<Partial<T>>;
}

function list<T>(items: Array<Partial<T>>): List<T> {
  return {items};
}

class Baz<T> {
  bar(list: List<T>) {
  }
}
```

Now, If I create a `Bar<Item>`, its `bar` method wants a `List<Item>`. However, if I use the convenience function `list()`, even though it returns `List<T>`, `T` is not inferred as `Item`, with each item being `Partial<Item>`; instead T is inferred as the intersection of all array elements, meaning it basically fails unless all elements contain the same properties.

This means that the following does not compile:

```
new Baz<Item>().bar(list([{foo: 'FOO', bar: 42}, {bar: 42}]))

-> TS2322: 'foo' does not exist in Partial<{bar: number}>
```

Here, `T` was inferred as `Partial<{bar: number}` which is the intersection of both elements.

The following works since adding `undefined` to the second element widens the inferred `T` to become `{foo: string; bar: number} | {foo: undefined; bar: number}`:

```
new Baz<Item>().bar(list([{foo: 'FOO', bar: 42}, {bar: 42, foo: undefined}]))
```

The following of course also works, since `T` does not have to be inferred at all:

```
new Baz<Item>().bar(list<Item>([{foo: 'FOO', bar: 42}, {bar: 42}]))
```

Question: Is there a way to define a function having a generic parameter `T` and taking array elements related to `T` so that `T` is inferred from the return type instead of the intersection of the array elements, in other words allowing non-intersecting array elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe we have a deal with [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) .

Next array `[{ foo: 'FOO', bar: 42 }, { bar: 42 }]` is infered to :

```js
({
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
} | {
    bar: number;
    foo?: undefined;
})[]
```

But in our case we have function with generic. Hence, `T` is infered to `{bar: number}` for the same reason as :

```js
type A = { foo: string, bar: number };
type B = { bar: number };
type C = A | B;

type Keys = keyof C // 'bar'
```

Because `bar` is a shared property between both unions.

We can skip excess property checking in this way:

```js
type Item = { foo: string, bar: number };

// A List<Item> may contain items containing partial Items such as {foo: 'FOO'}, {bar: 42}
interface List<T> {
    items: Array<Partial<T>>;
}

function list<T>(items: Array<Partial<T>>): List<T> {
    return { items };
}

class Baz<T> {
    bar(list: List<T>) {
    }
}

const arr = [{ foo: 'FOO', bar: 42 }, { bar: 42 }];


const result = new Baz<Item>().bar(list(arr))
```

Just assign array to the variable.

**The better option**

Just add extra generic:

```js
type Item = { foo: string, bar: number };

// A List<Item> may contain items containing partial Items such as {foo: 'FOO'}, {bar: 42}
type List<T> = {
    items: Array<Partial<T>>;
}

// extra generic here
function list<T, A extends Array<Partial<T>>>(items: A): List<T> {
    return { items }
}


class Baz<T> {
    bar<U extends T>(list: List<U>) {
    }
}

const result = new Baz<Item>().bar(list([{ foo: '1', bar: 2 }, { bar: 2 }])) // ok
```

Comment: Awesome. Once again you've saved me! :) Funny thing is - wiser from that other question you helped me with recently - I did try several combinations of adding an additional generic parameter to try to decouple `T` from the arguments and infer it from the expected return type instead, but I must have messed up, because this works. As does `list<T, A extends T>(items: Array<Partial<A>>): List<T> {`.

Comment: I would say that this problem is only a 50% similar. While you should add here extra generic, the problem was caused by excess property checking. Generics are tricky ))